# Is this MYSQL or PHP Error? When mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have an error like this :

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lab\try.php on line 40
```

The query is :

```
$graphquery = mysql_query ("SELECT
  $cluster,
  SUM(IF(idx=3,1,0)) AS green,
  SUM(IF(idx=2,1,0)) AS yellow,
  SUM(IF(idx=1,1,0)) AS red
FROM (SELECT
        $cluster
        $xcond
        ,LEAST(999 $acond) idx 
      FROM table
      WHERE date >= '". $startDate ."'
          AND date <= '". $endDate ."'
          AND $regional = '$gregcond'
          AND $latitude IS NOT NULL 
      GROUP BY $cluster, $lac, $mainid
      HAVING $cluster IS NOT NULL
$paraxcond
      ) A
GROUP BY $cluster");
```

If I echo the query, it will be like this (no error, perfect result too btw) :

```
SELECT
  cluster,
  SUM(IF(idx=3,1,0)) AS green,
  SUM(IF(idx=2,1,0)) AS yellow,
  SUM(IF(idx=1,1,0)) AS red
FROM (SELECT
        cluster,
        ROUND(AVG(some_value_Index))    some_value_Index,
        LEAST(999, AVG(some_value_Index) )    idx
      FROM TABLE
      WHERE tanggal >= '2012-07-10'
          AND tanggal <= '2012-08-02'
          AND Regional = 'Regional_Example'
          AND Latitude IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY cluster, Lac, ID
      HAVING cluster IS NOT NULL
          AND some_value_Index IN(3,2,1)) A
GROUP BY cluster
```

When I add mysql_error on that script, it sounds like this :

```
Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'LEAST'
```

And here is how I willing to use the MYSQL Query :

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array ($graphquery)
```

When I am ECHO the query and try it on SQLYOG or PHPMYADMIN there is no error contained, so Can anyone tell me where is the error please?

Comment: you don't show us what is `$graphquery` and you use `mysql_` which is even worse. Start using `PDO` or `MySQLi`.

Comment: $acond and $xcond is just a condition bro, I think there is nothing that will affect the script. The query is too complex I think, so I cant explain more details. But I'll wait your answers or another question to clear it :) Thanks btw

Comment: Try making your SQL Query a string prior to actually running the query (`$qryStr = "SELECT...";`). That way you can `echo` the `$qryStr` and see if one of the variables is causing an issue. Right now it's hard to tell because we don't know what's in `$cluster`, `$xcond`, etc.

Comment: alfasin : I have update it, there is the $graphquery. Sorry

Comment: Oke, I'll paste the query that have been ECHOed

Comment: @Giez: in general terms, while sometimes showing the PHP that generates a query is useful, when you get a MySQL error, that means the query (as executed) has a syntax error, and you should show what the ACTUAL query looks like. Just seeing some php variables means nothing to us.

Comment: I have update it @MarcB , thanks to tell me btw. I hope it will be more clear :)

Comment: If you have solved your answer, please post your solution to help future visitors (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a comma in the LEAST() function. LEAST expects 2 or more parameters. So the query will be.

```
mysql_query ("SELECT
  $cluster,
  SUM(IF(idx=3,1,0)) AS green,
  SUM(IF(idx=2,1,0)) AS yellow,
  SUM(IF(idx=1,1,0)) AS red
FROM (SELECT
        $cluster
        $xcond
        ,LEAST(999, $acond) idx 
      FROM table
      WHERE date >= '". $startDate ."'
          AND date <= '". $endDate ."'
          AND $regional = '$gregcond'
          AND $latitude IS NOT NULL 
      GROUP BY $cluster, $lac, $mainid
      HAVING $cluster IS NOT NULL
$paraxcond
      ) A
GROUP BY $cluster");
```

I changed `LEAST(999 $acond)` to `LEAST(999, $acond)`

Comment: Thanks mate, but check the questions once more. It will be more clear to understand maybe :D